# Is an interior point's neighbourhood based on the radius in X or $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

The definition in Rudin states a point $x$ is interior to $E$ if $\exists r>0, s.t. N_r(x) \subset E$. Is this r bound to values of $E\subset X$ or $\mathbb{R}$?

Note: I also realized that it wouldn't make much sense if we are talking about $\mathbb{R}^k$ for $k>1$.

Comment: $N_r(x)$ should be the metric ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$. That is $N_r(x) = \{ y\in X: d(x, y)< r\}$.

Comment: @JohnMa, I was wondering if radius $r\in\mathbb{R}$ or $r \in X$? Actually I guess the latter wouldn't make such sense

Comment: $r\in \mathbb R$. Indeed $r>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The r refers to metric distance function and that always returns a non-negative real value.  So it refers to R, and wouldn't be well defined otherwise.

$N_r(x) = \{p \in E| d(p, x) < r\}$

as d(p,x) is a real value, r must be too.

Answer (score 0):

Restricting $r$ to values in $X$ won't work.  For example, let $X=(1,2)$.  We want this to be an open set.  Now $N_{1/2}(3/2)\subseteq X$ even though $1/2\notin X$.

Comment: Do you mean $1/2 \not\in X$?

Comment: Ah yes.  Thanks.